# Is it possible to get the turrets out of the sewer?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In the mission where you have to defuse a bomb in the sewers there are 2 hackable turrets. Has anyone figured out a way to get these outside? It would be fun to drop this outside the police station and annoy the cops.

Comment: I've never tried this, although I don't think you can take them up ladders.  However, there is one turret in a later mission that you can bring into a boss fight, which was quite useful :)

Comment: Yeah I've done that. As well you can take the turret down the Funicular in the Montreal level. I'll try again. You can throw them up then climb the ladder but getting them through the manhole is tough.

Comment: Well, why not? If you got needed upgrades and if you find sewer exit low enough - you can through it out and get some fun =)

Answer (score 1):

Unless one of the manholes is low enough that you can /throw/ the turrets out, there is no way to carry them up a ladder.

In theory if you were to spend long enough gathering movable objects it would be possible to drop enough of them into the sewers to allow you to jump/carry it close enough to the manhole to throw it out.

Comment: Old news now but yes I was able to do it. Grab a turret, go to the ladder, up-grab, up-grab, up-grab - until you come out. It took some practice but it does work.